# Fix faulty MySQL installation on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, mysql, lamp

I'm installing a [L]AMP stack on my newly installed OS with apache2 and php7 installed so far. Now I'm up to MySQL, and following the directions [here](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486) I've hit a snag.

First of all there was no bind-address line in my.cnf.

Secondly the file is binary-encoded.

How do I remedy this?

I did `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` – how do I uninstall it to retry?

I tried to start to follow the instructions [here](https://linuxscriptshub.com/uninstall-completely-remove-mysql-ubuntu-16-04/) but
after entering the first line:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
```

I got this error in return:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo su
pgrep apt|xargs kill -9
rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock* -f
dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Thank you, with that I was able to successfully un- and reinstall mysql-server, but now I'm at the part in the first tutorial where the bind-address is absent and I'm unsure as to how to proceed.

Comment: Never mind I just ran mysql_secure_installation, seems to have worked out alright

Comment: @MWA missing bind address in the configuration means mysql accepts all connection from all interfaces, if you want local only to access it, add this to my.cnf
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

and restart the mysql.

or re-initialize the mysql installation. 

Did I solve your problem?